# Powershell script to delete all files older than one day, in directories with specific words in the name

Tags: powershell

I need a script to search through a root directory (such as C:\inetpup\wwwroot\Listings) and find all subdirectories that have the word "ImageCache" in the directory name (such as 114WestImageCache, 214OakImageCache, etc), and then delete all files *inside* those directories that are more than thirty days old.  The closest I've gotten so far is:

```
dir C:\inetpup\wwwroot\Listings\ | where {$_.name -ne 'ImageCache'}| Remove-Item -Recurse -force
```

But that also deletes everything (regardless of date) except the one directory named only "ImageCache".  I want to leave the directories alone that don't have "ImageCache" in their name, and only delete the files *inside* the ImageCache directories that are older than 30 days.  Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will do it for you.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Listings" -Recurse -Force | ? { $_.DirectoryName -like "*ImageCache*" -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | % { $_.Delete() }
```

The `?` clause checks the `DirectoryName` against anything containing the string you are looking for.  This will hit files also in subdirectories of the ImageCache directory as well, hopefully what you like.  It also checks against a `CreationTime` less than the current date minus one day - that is, older than a day.  The `%` then deletes all matches - remove that if you want to test this first.